# SwiftUI Button action called on NavigationLink press, and the main view does not update

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationlink

I have a SwiftUI view that looks like this (simplified for privacy reasons):

```swift
var body: some View {

    HStack {

        Button(action: {

            self.completed.toggle()

        }) {

            Text(self.title)

        }

        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(task: self.task)) {

            Text(self.title)

        }

    }

}
```

The navigation works just fine, and the `DetailView` has the updated status (`toggle` just toggles the status), however when I go back to the main view, the status is not updated. Why is this?

And I need the button to act differently to the text - is this possible? I want the button press to perform the button action, and the rest of the row to act as the `NavigationLink`. How can I do this?

The `self.completed` is a `CompletionStatus` class that is an `ObservableObject`, with a `@Published` property `status`. `task` is `@State` of type `Task`, which contains the `completed` (CompletionStatus) property. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Here are the `Task` and `CompletionStatus` structs and classes respectively:

```swift
struct Task: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID()
    var title: String
    var description: String
    @ObservedObject var completed: CompletionStatus
}

class CompletionStatus: ObservableObject {
    @Published var status: Bool

    init(_ defaultValue: Bool) {

        self.status = defaultValue

    }

    func toggle() -> CompletionStatus {

        self.status = !self.status
        return self

    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably help to see your `Task` and `CompletionStatus` classes as well.

Comment: Edited @graycampbell.

Comment: For the button its easy. Use a onTapGesture on something (e.g. Image) instead of a button.

Comment: Thanks @MarcT., but that's working fine - the issue is that whenever I click on the Text, not the Button, the button's action is fired. Sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: Thanks @MarcT. - that works perfectly! Thank you so much! That fixed my problem, and making `completed` to `@ObservedObject` made sure it updated. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you so much!